# Convert doubles array to a dense vector in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to run a relatively simple query based on the dense vector [examples](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch):

```
{
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['vector']) + 1.0",
                "params": {"query_vector": vector}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `vector` value that I'm passing to the query is a simple array of doubles with size matching those of vectors stored in the database. However, when I attempt to run the query, I'm getting this error:

```
     'script_stack': ["cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['vector']) + 1.0",
     '                                         ^---- HERE'],
```

Is there a way to force the query parameter type?

> **class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles** cannot be cast to class **org.elasticsearch.xpack.vectors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues** (org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; org.elasticsearch.xpack.vectors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues is in unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @72ee5d84)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I wasn't properly defining the vector field in my index mapping. Have you explicitly defined the field in your mapping, and is the type right? Should be something like

```
{
    "properties": {
      "vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 32
      }
}
```

Where dims=The number of values in your vector

Comment: You are right, I forgot to include an answer. Turns out the index was deleted and recreated from an example, which changed the type to double (array). Deleting the index again and creating it with explicit types solved the issue.